error: binding reference of type ‘std::map<int, mapValue>&’ to ‘const std::map<int, mapValue>’ discards qualifiers
I have a map that is part of an object that I want to make sure that I never accidentally mess up; however, when compiling, I get the following error:
./test.cpp: In member function ‘std::map<int, mapValue>& myClass::getMap() const’:
./test.cpp:22:49: error: binding reference of type ‘std::map<int, mapValue>&’ to ‘const std::map<int, mapValue>’ discards qualifiers
   22 |     map<key, mapValue> &getMap() const { return m; }
      |  

Here is my code:
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct mapValue
{
  int num;
  string data;
};

class myClass
{
  public:
    typedef int key; //hopefully this helps future people searching for a similar error

    void adjustMap(int index, mapValue mv)
    {
      m[index] = mv;
    }

    map<key, mapValue> &getMap() const { return m; }

  private:
    map<key, mapValue> m = {
      {0, {0, "Hi!"}},
      {1, {0, "Hello"}},
      {2, {1, "Goodbye"}}
    };
};

void operateWithMapData(const myClass &c) //I don't want to accidentally mess up
                                          //the map or anything in c
{
  const auto &m = c.getMap(); //Seriously, I do NOT want to edit this map.

  for(auto &kv : m)
  {
    cout << kv.first << ":" << kv.second.data << ":" << kv.second.num << endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  myClass c;
  c.adjustMap(5, {8, "Bye"});

  operateWithMapData(c);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

I want to make sure that when I'm working on operateWithMapData that I don't accidentally insert, change, or delete any existing values.
Normally, I know that when I make c a const reference, then I'm not:

pointlessly coping over large amounts of data (pass by reference part)
making it immutable (the const part)

If I were to just do that and remove const from myClass::getMap() and leave it in operateWithMapData then:

It still doesn't compile
That could mean I have access to a mutable version of the raw map that I could screw up somewhere else.

I guess my question is two parts:

How do I correctly accomplish what I want to?
Can I get a good detailed explanation on what this error means so if I see something like it in the future, then I can fix it on my own.

Here are some related questions, but I don't think they solve my problem..
Binding to reference of type discards qualifiers
How to return a class object by reference in C++?
Error: Binding reference of type '&' to 'const  discards qualifiers'

Change map<key, mapValue> &getMap() const { return m; } to const map<key, mapValue> &getMap() const { return m; }? Or to map<key, mapValue> &getMap() { return m; }?

getMap cannot be marked const and return a non-const reference a member.

On a different note, please don't use classes as simple multi-variable container with getter functions that return whole internal data-structures. Think about the purpose of the class, its behavior, and design and model the class on purpose and behavior instead.

@Someprogrammerdude 100% on the second comment, I just wanted to provide a MRE.

You have a constant myClass object, which means you can not modify it or its members.
Your getMap() function is marked as const to make it possible to call on constant objects. But that const modifier also promises that the function will not do anything that can lead to modifications of member variables.
By returning a reference to a non-constant map, you break that promise, because through it you can modify the map inside the constant object.
Therefore your best solution is to make the function return a references to a constant map:
// Constant qualified function, return a reference to a constant map
std::map<key, mapValue> const &getMap() const { return m; }


If you want to also be able to use getMap() to return a reference to the map which can be modified, you could add an overload that is not const qualified:
// Non-constant qualified function, returns a reference to a non-const map
std::map<key, mapValue> &getMap() { return m; }


The problem is that myClass::getMap() is marked as a const method, but returns a non-const reference to a member. This is not allowed since it can indirectly lead to modifying the object that holds the member.
If you do not want to modify the map, simply return a const reference to it:
//-----------------vvvvv------------------------------
map<key, mapValue> const & getMap() const { return m; }

Alternatively if you do want to be able to change the map and you need a non-const reference, remove the const qualifier from the method:
map<key, mapValue> & getMap() { return m; }

